# If $n\neq m$ then $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I want to prove that if $n\neq m$ then $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$.

This deceptively simple topology question came up on an algebraic topology worksheet on which the rest of the questions centre around the Mayer-Vietoris sequence and degrees of maps. I have to admit I have little idea about how to proceed, except maybe to use homotopy types (and I'm not even sure how to start there). A hint or two would be very handy...

Comment: @user8268: Yes I believe I can. $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\} \simeq S^{n-1}$, $\mathbb{R}^m\setminus\{0\} \simeq S^{m-1}$. But if $S^{n-1}$ and $S^{m-1}$ were homotopy equivalent, then $H_*(S^{n-1}) = H_*(S^{m-1})$, which is false. So this gives that $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^m\setminus \{0\}$ are not even homotopy equivalent. Ah, I think I see how to proceed with the last bit now, thanks to Aaron's answer below. Cheers! :)

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34232/injective-maps-mathbbrn-to-mathbbrm

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hint: If $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a homeomorphism, then $\mathbb{R}^m\setminus x$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \varphi(x)$.  Compute the homology.

Comment: haha, my kind of thinking ;)

Comment: @gfes Indeed!  Actually, when I hit submit, I saw your answer beat mine by 36 seconds.  But mine is longer, so I'm going to call it a tie. :P

Comment: I think I see it now! A little question because I haven't had enough sleep: is $\phi(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus x) = \phi(\mathbb{R}^n) \setminus \phi(x)$ a set theoretic result or is that specifically because $\phi$ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: @Fahad Sperinck That is completely set theoretic, using just that $\varphi$ is a bijection.  If $\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(x))$ had more than one point, the map wouldn't work.  However, the fact that restricted map is still a homeomorphism comes from the definition of the subspace topology.  More generally, if $U\subset X$ and $\varphi:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism, it restricts to a homeomorphism $U\to \varphi(U)$.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Try removing a point and computing the homology.

Comment: Thanks! This was there first and would have done the trick, but I read both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to compare the one-point compactifications of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$, ie. $\mathbb{S}^n$ and $\mathbb{S}^m$ respectively, for example by computing the homology.